vue tailwindcss radiobutton styling
I am trying to make a radio button component in vue and style it with accordance to some props, I copied a simple implementation from https://flowbite.com/docs/forms/radio to style it with respect to what I like.
Here's the snippet before my styling:
<template>
  <div class="flex items-center mb-4">

    <div class="flex items-center mb-4">
      <input :id="id" type="radio" :value="value" :name="name"
             class="
             w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300
             focus:ring-blue-500
             dark:focus:ring-blue-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800
             focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600
    ">
      <label :for="id" class="ms-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">Default radio</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

import {Color} from "../composables/useColor.ts";

const props = withDefaults(
    defineProps<{
      name: string
      id: string
      value: string
      checked: boolean
      primaryColor: Color
      secondaryColor: Color
    }>(), {
      value: "",
      secondaryColor: "gray",
      primaryColor: "azure",
      checked: false

    }
)

</script>

and this is how it looks.

the problem is that the css is not working and if I change all grays into red I notice no difference. I think either the browsers are overwriting my style or there's something I'm missing in tailwindcss.
The styling that they showed in the website mentioned above has blue

So I guess it's obvious that something is missing although I copied the exact code to my project.
My question in general is:

How to avoid browser overwriting my tailwindcss?
How to style a radio-button in tailwindcss properly?
what is wrong with the code I have already?


Can you add the css as well, that you have tried?

@YashMaheshwari I only use tailwindcss so apart from the code I added there's nothing more in my component :)

Can you create a sandbox/fiddle where this issue can be generated?

Tailwind CSS is correctly installed and configured in your project.
also check your tailwind.config.js file and ensure it's included in your project build process.

@KishanDobariya yep it is installed correctly because I have other components in the project and styled them using tailwindcss...

@YashMaheshwari How do I make the sandbox? what should I do and where

You can create a reproducible example here: https://play.vuejs.org/ or https://codesandbox.io/ or https://playcode.io/vue or https://jsfiddle.net/

What do you see in the browser devtools? Is your CSS there? Overriden? Or something else? This could help us narrow down the issue.
